# Reject and edit ― bad call?

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

Yesterday I suggested [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20003426):

[image: Suggested edit]

It was rejected, so I thought "OK, let’s see what I can learn here". When I opened of the review, I was greeted by:

> Rejected 13 hours ago:
>
> Community♦ reviewed this 13 hours ago: Reject
>
> This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed.
>
> Ketan Akbari reviewed this 13 hours ago: Approve

Wondering what critical issues my edit had ignored, I went to the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42212845/revisions) where I found this:

[image]

#### Let's call it irony

As you can see, this edit does ***not*** fix issues like salutations and does not correct the grammar, in fact, it is made worse in one place. I did spot one or two things I could have edited better, but I can't help but feel that my edit did a much better job than this one. What should I do about this? I don't like the fact that the reviewer rejected the edit, yet made a worse one.

Comment: Yes, let's <-- see what I did there? :)

Comment: @Mike: Oh, no, in the bold text too! It took me a little while to realise after reading your comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like part of this is a bug; usually, the rejecting user is displayed as well as Community. But not in this case, even though the reject message does indicate a "Reject and Edit":

> This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed.

This issue has been [observed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295043/336144) [previously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305813/community-rejects-edit-with-incorrect-reason?noredirect=1&lq=1) on Meta.SE with several bug reports over the last few months.

---

Regardless, your edit does look better than  what replaced it. You can always suggest the edit again, or otherwise just move on and contribute to other questions—there are always more questions in need of a good editor!

If you notice a pattern of a user rejecting valid edits, you can flag one of the user's posts with a custom flag to raise attention to the moderators. This is useful in cases  of blatant abuse, though I'm not sure if that's the case here or simply one decision that's not quite right. If you are concerned about a particular user's reviews, note some obviously wrong reviews and include the links in a flag.

Comment: You're right, it is a bug. It seems to only pop up when the message `This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed.` is used.

Comment: Also, how to flag one of these edit reviews if the user who rejected the edit is not shown?

Comment: @Graipher You can use the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42212845/timeline) to figure out that the last editor did in fact reject and edit. An 'S' appears next to the simultaneous events (rejection and editing) when you hover which can help you figure it out. In a flag, you would probably need to point that out, or choose a more obvious case; it's not exactly noticeable, as you've no doubt realised. Luckily, this is a rare bug; most of the time you can link to the review and it will say "Reject and Edit" as expected.